# Bash case using environment variables

Tags: bash, variables, case, environment

I want to use a button on my thinkpad x200 laptop to rotate between portrait and landscape, if I am in landscape it goes to portrait and vice versa. I am using an environment variable $RotationState with values of normal and right to keep track of where I am.  I can set the variable fine but can't get the case structure to work right

: echo $RotationState
returns Normal

Now

```
#!/bin/bash
case "$RotationState" in
 "Normal")
      /home/laugh/bin/right.sh 
      export RotationState="Right"
      echo $RotationState ;;

  "Right")
     /home/laugh/bin/normal.sh  
     export RotationState="Normal"
     echo $RotationState ;;
   *) echo FAILED
esac
```

all I ever get is failed and it is driving me nuts

Comment: You can't change a variable value from a subshell.

Comment: `export RotationState=Normal; /path/to/your/script.sh`

Comment: agree with `export ..`. Add an `echo RState=$RotationState` **before** the case statement to see confirm. Otherwise, code looks good. Good luck.